# list all users which have a particular status on any day over a 18 month period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I run some courses and have a table of orders every order moves through a few statuses before we get to complete but some orders also get canceled. The statuses changes are recorded in a status change table (see below)

```
statushistoryid| statusdate  | orderid   |  statusid
---------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------
          1234 | 2021-03-21  |  13       |  completed
          1235 | 2021-03-21  |  76       |  pending
          1236 | 2021-03-25  |  45       |  offer
          1237 | 2021-03-26  |  104      |  offer 
          1238 | 2021-03-26  |  61       |  completed
          1239 | 2021-03-26  |  123      |  completed
          1240 | 2016-03-26  |  345      |  pending
          1241 | 2016-03-27  |  124      |  offer
          1242 | 2016-03-27  |  104      |  completed                   
          1243 | 2016-03-28  |  156      |  offer
          1244 | 2016-03-28  |  123      |  canceled
          1245 | 2016-03-28  |  180      |  completed
```

I am trying to run some year-on-year analysis to compare how many orders had a status of completed for a particular day. So it is easy enough for me to look at any order that has ever had a status of completed but if the canceled the following day I would need to exclude that from my completed numbers for the following day.

So I can have about 2000 orders with a completed status for each day (as people can order a couple of years in advance of the start date) so the table would need to have about 2000 records in the table for each day and the history will go back about 18 months (540 days). So the table could be just over a million records, which I don't think is an issue. so the final table will just need two fields (see below).

```
orderid        | Date        | 
---------------+-------------+
          1234 | 2021-03-26  |
          1265 | 2021-03-26  |
          1336 | 2021-03-26  |
          1334 | 2021-03-26  |
          1260 | 2021-03-26  |
          1039 | 2021-03-26  |
          1740 | 2016-03-26  |
          1531 | 2016-03-26  |
          1442 | 2016-03-26  |                  
          1383 | 2016-03-26  |
          1994 | 2016-03-26  |
          1299 | 2016-03-26  |
```

So if anyone knows if there is a way to do this I would appreciate any advice, if you need further clarification let me know.

Edit - I just thought of some logic if we have a field with the order completed date and then another field which calculates the number of days it is at completed status. would the help to create a daily record of orders with a completed status?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Without DDL we can assume that every column is `NVarChar(Max)`. What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: my original query is more complex as I have a lot joins in there but I tried to simplify things to put on this forum.  I tried to paste the query her but it was too long. My attempt tried looking at the order id and taking the max status if it had a completed status but then it missed if the cancelled after they had that status

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE     @StatusTable    TABLE   (statushistoryid int, statusdate date, orderid int, statusid varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @StatusTable    VALUES
        (1234,  '2021-03-21',   13 ,    'completed' )
    ,   (1235,  '2021-03-21',   76 ,    'pending'   )
    ,   (1236,  '2021-03-25',   45 ,    'offer'     )
    ,   (1237,  '2021-03-26',   104,    'offer'     )
    ,   (1238,  '2021-03-26',   61 ,    'completed' )
    ,   (1239,  '2021-03-26',   123,    'completed' )
    ,   (1240,  '2016-03-26',   345,    'pending'   )
    ,   (1241,  '2016-03-27',   124,    'offer'     )
    ,   (1242,  '2016-03-27',   104,    'completed' )
    ,   (1243,  '2016-03-28',   156,    'offer'     )
    ,   (1244,  '2016-03-28',   123,    'canceled'  )
    ,   (1245,  '2016-03-28',   180,    'completed' )
;

DECLARE @StatusID   varchar(20) = 'completed'
    ,   @Date       date        =   '20210326'
    ,   @Days       int         =   540 
;

SELECT  DISTINCT
        SCom.*

FROM            @StatusTable    SCom
LEFT    JOIN    @StatusTable    SCan    ON  SCan.orderid    = SCom.orderid
                                        AND SCan.statusid   =   'canceled'
                                        
WHERE   SCan.orderid                            IS  NULL    -- No canceled
    AND CHARINDEX(@StatusID, SCom.statusid)     >   0       -- contains word 'completed'
    AND DATEDIFF(day, Scom.statusdate, @Date)   <=  @Days   -- go back @Days days from @date date
;
```

Comment: You might need to check if the canceled date is >= completed date; i don't know if you allow any other status after canceled, that might result in a completed status.

Comment: Hi Thanks Andy3B but yes there some other statuses after cancelled so if it moves to any status after anything which contains completed (but  we also have the status 'completed deposit' which is the same as a completed order but they just paid deposit) then that would mean they would be removed. the other thing missing is this would not provide the completed count for any given day which is the main thing I am trying to acheive to do the year-on-year analysis

Comment: Answer was edited. added the rules to catch completed and completed deposit, plus the days range.